# Pluralization on symfomy command

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-3.4

I've created a commmando which needs  pluralization to send some emails

```
//without pluralization works fine
//$body = $this->translator->trans('expiration.password.reminder.body', $email_params, 'emails');
 $body = $this->translator->transChoice('expiration.password.reminder.subject', 102,[], 'emails');
```

this is the message to translate ans pluralize

```
expiration.password.reminder.body: '<p>Dear %name% %surname%,</p>Your password is going to expire in %$day_to_remind% days.
```

but in the sent email the shown text is not complete:

```
Your password is going to expire
```

I don't know what is wrong, anyone know a way which works on symfony3.4 and is not deprecated at symfony4.4?

Answer (score 0):

The `%$day_to_remind%`parameter should be named `%count%` instead, as symfony populates it automatically given the second parameter. And you should also provide the singular form [according to the format](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/translation.html#pluralization):

```
# Message key and content shortened
'Your password is going to expire in 1 day|Your password is going to expire in %count% days'
```

This *is* deprecated in 4.4, though, but it still works, since [the replacement wasn't introduced until 4.2](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-2-intlmessageformatter) and as per the symfony stability promise,  there are no breaks in minor releases.